# React Native: Showing Recent Errors Only Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: xcode, react-native, build, cocoapods

I am getting below issue while buuilding react native project from xcode:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92FZD.png)

I tried removing the podfile.lock, Pods folder and did 'pod install' as well, but no luck.

Also, when i am running the application from terminal using the command 'npx react-native run-ios', getting below error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iokgZ.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.